# Необходимо вывести в консоль количество положительных цифр попавших в консоль. Заранее благодарю

Tags: javascript

```
    const max = 25,
          min = -25;
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          const getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
          if (getRandom>=0){
            let result = [getRandom];
             console.log(result)
          }
          
          
        }
```

Comment: "Необходимо вывести в консоль количество положительных цифр попавших в консоль." --- шшшшшшто?

Comment: Круг замкнулся.

Comment: не сами числа , а их количество

Comment: а что такое положительные/отрицательные цифры?

Comment: с положительным знаком, отрицательным знаком (+/-)

Comment: Цифры - символы, из которых мы составляем числа "на письме". Положительными и отрицательными могут быть именно числа, а не цифры. И судя по вашему комментарию под ответом, вам надо вывести в консоль количество положительных чисел, из числа получаемых случайным выбором в рамках определенного диапазона. Во всех смыслах лучше вынести формирование случайного набора определенной длины из определенного диапазона в отдельную функцию, а уже результаты анализировать отдельно. В данном случае - `result_arr.filter(n => n > 0).length`, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так что ли?

```js
const max = 25,
      min = -25;

let counter = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    
    if (getRandom > 0) {
        counter ++;
    }
}

console.log(counter);
```

или с выводом чисел

```js
const max = 25,
      min = -25;

let numbers = Array();

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    
    if (getRandom > 0) {
        numbers.push(getRandom);
    }
}

console.log(numbers.length)
console.log(numbers.join(' '));
```

Comment: Так. Благодарю.

Comment: сделано, хотя можно было бы и через `filter`, чтобы код сделать покороче